# Building neutrino from source for use with lnd

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, compiling, compact-client-side-block-filters

I am trying to build [neutrino](https://github.com/lightninglabs/neutrino), [to use with lnd](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md#using-neutrino).

However I cannot find any installation instructions.

[Someone else also asked for install instructions a few months ago and got no reply](https://github.com/lightninglabs/neutrino/issues/252).

I have installed go version `go1.19 linux/amd64`.

Even though I am not familiar with go, I am trying to guess the steps.

This is what I tried first:

```
git clone https://github.com/lightninglabs/neutrino
cd neutrino
git checkout v0.15.0
make clean
make
```

This is the output from make:

```
 Compiling neutrino.
 go build -v github.com/lightninglabs/neutrino/...
```

I can't find any binaries after doing this.

Then, I tried the following:

```
 go build -v -o ~/neutrino *.go
```

This created an [ar archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) which is not executable:

```
 $ file ~/neutrino 
 /home/alexg/neutrino: current ar archive
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong.

Why can't I find the installation instructions? Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, `neutrino` is not a standalone node but a library that `lnd` uses to be able to run in "neutrino" mode.

To use `lnd` with a `neutrino` backend, compile `lnd` from the source and then run with the following options:

```
 lnd --bitcoin.active --bitcoin.testnet --debuglevel=debug \
       --bitcoin.node=neutrino --neutrino.connect=faucet.lightning.community
```

(Taken from https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md#using-neutrino)

This [issue](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/issues/3975) also mentions that you may need to compile LND with experimental flags in order to use neutrino, although I am unsure if this is still the case.

Comment: I feel very dumb now. I was 100% sure that it was some stand-alone daemon. Thank you!